# Error running Form Builder on Ubuntu

Tags: orbeon

I have downloaded Orbeon Form builder Community Edition 4.3 and deployed the orbeon.war in Ubuntu OS. The home page is loaded. When i click on the Form Builder image it keeps loading for quite a long time and shows an error - "Orbeon Forms - An Error has Occurred". I could not resolve the problem. Please help me identify the problem with my system configuration. Please let me know if I have to change any firewall settings in my system.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be an issue with the JDK you are using. Try to make sure you are using Oracle Java. Also, there should be an error in log files.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question to provide a definitive answer, but here are a few suggestions:

- Make sure you're using Oracle Java.
- Make sure the `WEB-INF/exist-data` directory is writable. (This is where the embedded database eXist will write the forms/data when using Form Builder, at least by default.)
- Check the `orbeon.log` after you tried to access Form Builder. Are there any errors?